# Spring-kafka support for only executing SeekToTimestamp once

Tags: spring-kafka

My use-case is to set consumer group offset based on timestamp.
For this I am using seekToTimestamp method of ConsumerSeekCallback inside onPartitionsAssigned() method of ConsumerSeekAware.

Now when I started my application it seeks to the timestamp I specified but during rebalancing, it seeks to that timestamp again.

I want this to happen only when if ConsumerGroup Offset is less than the offsets at that particular timestamp, if it's greater than that then it should not seek.

Is there a way we can achieve this or does Spring-Kafka provides some listeners for the new ConsumerGroup so when the new consumer group gets created it will invoke seek based on timestamp otherwise will use the existing offsets?

```
public class KafkaConsumer implements ConsumerSeekAware {

@Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
 long timestamp = 1623775969;
    callback.seekToTimestamp(new ArrayList<>(assignments.keySet()), timestamp);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a boolean field (`boolean seeksDone;`) to your implementation; set it to true after seeking and only seek if it is false.

You have to decide, though, what to do if you only get partitions 1 and 3 on the first rebalance and 1, 2, 3, 4 on the next.

Not an issue if you only have one application instance, of course. But, if you need to seek each partition when it is first assigned, you'll have to track the state for each partition.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I have 30 partitions in a topic and 3 instances running with 10 concurrent consumers each. So want to execute seek for each partitioned assigned only once. I can keep a Map<Partition,Boolean> but this will be local to one instance, or will this work during the first seek for all the instances?

Comment: I think when rebalance happens and different partitions get assigned to an instance then boolean Map will not work in that case.

Comment: No; each instance is independent; I guess you can assume that the other instance already did the seek and the instance they are reassigned to can process from where the dead instance left off; so a simple boolean is enough. If you add a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` you can do the seeks there and commit the new position so if a rebalance occurs you won't have to seek in the new instance.

Comment: Gary, what happens when app(s) restart? Especially if you do not want to seek in subsequent restarts or deployments?

Comment: You would need to handle that yourself; perhaps via a system property.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have a requirement to deploy application to new cluster and seek to timestamp needs to happen only first time application starts. For subsequent starts/deploys I prefer latest. Multiple instances. Is this still the right approach for that. Looked at SeekToCurrentErrorHandler but that gives less flexibility when it’s just one off use case. Thanks